# Example of using UDP in obj-c/C++?

Tags: c++, objective-c, udp, ios

I'm making an iOS app - real-time game, wanna use UDP protocol. I'm searching a lot for examples/guides, but can't find any.
Also, the software on the server will use C++, and I've searched a lot and can't fina a nice way to use it, for begginers in C++...

I found that: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/samplecode/PictureSharing/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10000712-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2

But it's using TCP.

So, if anyone have an example of usuing UDP in objective-c and C++...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe have a look at UDT:

UDT -- UDP-based data transfer

http://udt.sourceforge.net/software.html

> The UDT software is a C++ library containing the UDT API implementation and programming examples. The most recent version is UDT version 4, including 3 separate packages: pure source code, GNU package, and pre-compiled WIN32/i386 version. All UDT releases can be downloaded from UDT SourceForge project web site.
>
> ...
>
> UDT supports Linux, Windows, OS X, and BSD.

Answer (score 0):

See also:

http://digitalpbk.blogspot.com/2007/10/unix-networking-sockets-udp-transmitter.html